# 2D графика в android: нарисовать круг

Tags: android, графика

Пытаюсь научиться работе с графикой. Теоретически, этот код должен рисовать круг желтый, но ничего не получается. Не подскажите, в чем проблема?

```
package com.example.matrici;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

  public class GraphicsDemo extends Activity {

    // @Override
    public void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
            setContentView(new Draw2D(this));  
    }}

package com.example.matrici;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Draw2D extends View{

    Paint paint = new Paint();    
    public Draw2D(Context context) {
            super(context);
        } 
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);       
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawCircle(150, 30, 25, paint);      
    }}
```

Comment: у меня встречный вопрос - зачем? я иногда вижу вопросы про 2д, но где ее можно применить и зачем?

Comment: пишу диплом. нужно изобразить расположение прямой на плоскости.

Comment: а что не получается? ошибки? или просто на экране нечего нету?

Comment: просто на экране ничего нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   // @Override
```

закоментировали, а ведь оно не зря ругалось, потому как имя метода **o**nCreate
пишется со строчной **o** , а Ваш **O**nCreate не вызывается системой  так как для неё это совсем другой метод

Comment: Спасибо. А вы не подскажите, каким образом передать данный из GraphicsDemo в класс Draw2D

Comment: @Ольга___ передавайте через конструктор. Заведите еще параметр(ы) в конструкторе Draw2D и передавайте через них